# glRotatef problem

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut

I am trying a very basic code sample. I draw an opengl object and with a keyboard I rotate it. I tried same thing without using keyboard. I open a thread and I invoked same `glRotatef` function (same `glrotatef` I use in keyboard function) for every 5 seconds. But there is no rotation. What is the problem? Here is my thread code below:

```
void movePlayer2()
{
  while(1)
  //if(key == 'a')
  { 
    Sleep(5000);
    glRotatef(25,1,0,0);
    //gluLookAt(0,0,0.01,0,0,-5,0,1,0);
    display();
  }
}
```

Comment: what does display() do? In particular are you sure you are calling glutPostRedisplay inside your infinite loop?

Comment: could you provide a little more code? your perspective setup / loop etc? ah and is it possible that you reset your matrix every frame?

Comment: I would try to get this working with a single thread first. Why do you have multiple threads anyway?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL contexts are tied to threads, i.e. as long as a OpenGL context is bound (by gl*MakeCurrent) only functions calls made from the thread the context has been bound to, will affect that context. You can bind a context to another thread (first unbind it). Or in simple words, it simply doesn't work the way you think.

However you approach is totally wrong anyway. OpenGL is not a scene graph. glRotatef affects just the modelview matrix. And OpenGL doesn't know objects, it just knows primitives.

The basic pattern in OpenGL is, that you set all the state you need, just right before drawing. So you call the display function in a loop, therein set viewport and projection, then iterate through all objects, for each object set the proper modelview matrix. And depending on your application you may do those steps multiple times within the display function. And in your case, what your timer should do is incrementing the rotation angle, which is then used within the display function to create the proper modelview matrix.

Answer (score -1):

here is my basic code :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    initGL(argc, argv);
    HANDLE thread_id2=CreateThread( NULL , 0 , (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)f , NULL , 0 , 0 );
    HANDLE thread_id22=CreateThread( NULL , 0 , (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)movePlayer2 , NULL , 0 , 0 );

    glutMainLoop();


    return 0;
}



void initGL(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutCreateWindow("deneme");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);




}




void display()
{


    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    glutWireTeapot(0.5);

    glutSwapBuffers();


}





void f()
{
while(1)

    {   


        Sleep(5000);

        glRotatef(0.2,1,0,0);

        glutPostRedisplay();
        printf("dsdasd\n");


        display();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @genpfault, looks like meant to edit this into his original question. @cemal, you can click the edit link in your original question to add this code sample there.